# Openldap how to use RFC2307AIX schema which support aixAuxAccount objectClass

Tags: aix, openldap

I'm setting up an Openldap system with two machines, include one Openldap Server (Redhat 6.4) and one Openldap Client (AIX 6.1)

Now I could create LDAP User and login in AIX machine with that account.

However, I want to use *hostsdeniedlogin* and *hostsallowedlogin* those are two attributes of **objectClass *aixauxaccount*** but my Openldap server doesn't have any Object like that.

I found an aix2307aix.schema on internet, but don't know how to use it.
[rfc2307aix.schema](http://patrickv.info/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2009/06/rfc2307aix.schema)

Beside that file, I also found: a file names **nisSchema.ldif** which have content in the following form:

```
dn:cn=schema
changetype: modify
replace: objectclasses
objectclasses: (
  1.3.18.0.2.6.472
  NAME 'aixAuxAccount'
  DESC 'Auxiliary AIX user information objectclass, for use with posixaccount an
d shadowaccount objectclasses'
  SUP top
  AUXILIARY
  MAY ( passwordChar $ adminGroupNames $ aIXDefaultMACLevel $ aIXFuncMode $ aIXi
sDCEExport $ aIXLowMACLevel $ aIXPromptMAC $ aIXScreens $ aIXUpperMACLevel $ aud
itClasses $ authMethod1 $ authMethod2 $ coreSizeLimit $ coreSizeLimitHard $ cPuS
ize $ cPuSizeHard $ dataSegSize $ dataSegSizeHard $ filePermMask $ fileSizeLimit
 $ fileSizeLimitHard $ groupList $ groupSwitchUserAllowed $ hostLastLogin $ host
LastUnsuccessfulLogin $ hostsAllowedLogin $ hostsDeniedLogin $ isAdministrator $
 isAccountEnabled $ isDaemon $ isLoginAllowed $ isRemoteAccessAllowed $ isSwitch
UserAllowed $ ixTimeLastLogin $ ixTimeLastUnsuccessfulLogin $ loginTimes $ maxFa
iledLogins $ maxLogin $ openFileLimit $ openFileLimitHard $ passwordCheckMethods
 $ passwordDictFiles $ passwordExpireTime $ passwordHistSize $ passwordMaxRepeat
edChars $ passwordMinAlphaChars $ passwordMinDiffChars $ passwordMinLength $ pas
swordMinOtherChars $ physicalMemLimit $ physicalMemLimitHard $ roleList $ StackS
izeLimit $ StackSizeLimitHard $ SystemEnvironment $ terminalAccess $ terminalLas
tLogin $ terminalLastUnsuccessfulLogin $ timeExpiredLogout $ timeExpireLockout $
 trustedPathStatus $ unsuccessfulLoginCount $ userEnvironment $ passwordFlags )
  )
```

And I just found the way to add the rfc2307aix.schema file as the following link
[how-to-add-a-new-schema-to-openldap](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/how-to-add-a-new-schema-to-openldap-2-4-11-a-700452/)

that schema seem to be added successfully, but I stuck with that nisSchema.ldif file found on AIX.

I attempted to use ldapadd, but not successful.

```
modifying entry "cn=schema,cn=config"
ldap_modify: Other (e.g., implementation specific) error (80)
```

Anyone know how to deal with this, please help!

Comment: This isn't clear. You loaded one schema but not the other? Which one did you need? If not the first, why did you load it?

Comment: Yes, my question is not clear because I still don't have much knowledge about schema in LDAP. For short, I want my OpenLDAP Server has that useable "aixAuxAccount" ObjectClass :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already had that "aixAuxAccount" ObjectClass. My AIX Client working fine now with 'hostsdeniedlogin' attribute. I had to clear the client cache and reconnect the Ldap Admin Tool to see the change. And don't need to use the **nisSchema.ldif**

For those, who dont know how to use the [rfc2307aix.schema](http://emmanuel.iffly.free.fr/doku.php?id=ldap:openldap_aix), please follow this thread:

[how-to-add-a-new-schema-to-openldap](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/how-to-add-a-new-schema-to-openldap-2-4-11-a-700452/)

Thank you, for your attention and helps.